# Unable to connect to MSSQLServer 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

I have setup SQL Server 2008 R2 on a desktop (*Windows 7*). All the client protocols are enabled. I am trying to connect to this instance from my laptop. The laptop and the desktop are on the same network domain. I am able to remote into this desktop. I have admin privileges on both these machines.

There is no firewall on the desktop, although there is a firewall on the laptop. From my laptop, I am able to connect to other sqlserver instances on the network. I have restarted the services on the desktop and also rebooted it. From the desktop, I am able to make a connection to sql server and work with the databases on it.

As my C# code was failing to make a connection, I used SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO. that too is failing. I am getting the following error on SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your desktop/sql server to listen on a static port (default 1433) so that your laptop can connect to it:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx

`Note:` Be sure to modify the **SQL Server Network Configuration** and `not` the **Client Configuration**

Your laptop only knows of the default SQL port 1433 and it sounds like your server is listening on a dynamic port which changes on each startup.

You can confirm your server is listening on 1433 by running this command:

`netstat -ano | find ":1433"`

You will see `LISTENING` next to your IP:1433.